# Get PDF of RecyclerView/Bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pdf-generation, android-bitmap

I want to create a Pdf from Recyclerview. I was able to get an image of a recyclerview before. I first obtained a bitmap and then converted it to an image. But I couldn't find the correct way to create a pdf. The recommended libraries are too old. I am looking for an updated solution.

This is my function to get a bitmap:

```
private fun getRecyclerViewScreenshotAsBitmap(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        defaultColor: Int = Color.WHITE
    ): Bitmap {
        recyclerView.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(recyclerView.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        )

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            recyclerView.width,
            recyclerView.measuredHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        );
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        canvas.drawColor(defaultColor)
        recyclerView.draw(Canvas(bitmap));

        return bitmap
    }
```

How to get a pdf from a bitmap or reyclerview?

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) help?

Comment: Yes, it saved me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a `canvas` from the inbuilt [PDFDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) class

```java
// Create the initial PDF page
int A4Short = 594; // Postscript points
int A4Long = 841; // Postscript points
int pageNumber = 1;

PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder pageBuilder = new
  PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(A4Short,A4Long, pageNumber);
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = pageBuilder.create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

Canvas pdfCanvas = page.getCanvas();
```

then instead of `recyclerView.draw(Canvas(bitmap));`

do

`recyclerView.draw(pdfCanvas);`

or you can draw the bitmap you have to the `pdfCanvas`

then close the page `document.finishPage(page);` and write to file `document.writeTo(outputstream);`

The problem you might have is that an A4 page is not that big as it is only 594 x 841 pixels and you might need to either break the recycler in to many pages or set a scale on the pdfCanvas `pdfCanvas.scale(scaleWidth, scaleWidth);`

You might also be better rather than trying to re-use a layout you have used on screen create a linearLayout just for create drawing to pdf as it might be easier to get it to fit to the page size/paginate.