# Convert entire view into PDF and open in pdf viewer

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, bitmap

Hey devs I want to export my app entire view into PDF file and open it in pdf viewer, I explore so many things on google but my problem is not solved what i do so far is make bitmap of entire view but not figure out how I export it into  PDF file, help regarding this would be appreciated

code i done so far is below:

```
  val date = Date()
        val format = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy_hh:mm:ss", date)
        try {
            val mainDir = File(
                requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FilShare"
            )
            if (!mainDir.exists()) {
                val mkdir = mainDir.mkdir()
            }
            path = "$mainDir/$u_id-$format.jpeg"
            view?.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
            val bitmap = view?.let { Bitmap.createBitmap(it.drawingCache) }
            view?.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
            val imageFile = File(path)
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
            bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream)
            fileOutputStream.flush()
            fileOutputStream.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get PDF of RecyclerView/Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75042612/get-pdf-of-recyclerview-bitmap)

Comment: Same thing here. Please use punctuation marks.