# How to Print pdf document of recyclwrVIew in android studio

Tags: android, pdf, android-recyclerview

This is Priyanshu Maurya . My problem is that how to print pdf document of my recycler view in android studio. my recycler View fetching data from sqlite database .

I have no Idea for this .

Comment: Related: [How to convert Android View to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29730402/208273)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get PDF of RecyclerView/Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75042612/get-pdf-of-recyclerview-bitmap)